# Crosswalk installation for ionic fail

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

I'm trying to install crosswalk for ionic framework through the official ionic site:

[Crosswalk installation](http://ionicframework.com/blog/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/)

After running **ionic browser add crosswalk** at cmd I get the following warning/error repeating about 15 times

**Fetching Android SDK API 19.1.0
Had an error fetching the Android SDK required for Crosswalk. (CLI v1.3.7)**

I've already downloaded the required SDK through the eclipse SDK manager but I keep getting the error.

I'm adding some relevant outputs:

ionic --version: 1.3.7

cordova --version: 4.2.0

node --version: v0.10.36

npm --version: 1.4.28

nvm --version: version 1.0.6

Comment: Have you linked the Android SDK in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: its seems that you or don't have installed android sdk 19.1 or you don't have the android in the path/ have variable android_home

Comment: I already have it:ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\yuv\Desktop\appdev - yuv\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk
ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=C:\Users\yuv\Desktop\appdev - yuv\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\platform-tools

Answer (score 0):

Could you please open Android SDK Manager to check if 19.1 is installed? BTW, for Crosswalk later than 11.40.271.0, please use Android SDK API level 21: android-21

Answer (score 0):

I had to add ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ to my path on OSX.